# Bounce Rate Query Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i am planning to implement a query for calculating the bounce rate using elasticsearch query.

can any body know how to use the input of aggreation results using script ?

```
{
   "aggs":{
      "monthly":{
         "date_histogram":{
            "field":"timestamp",
            "interval":"month",
            "script":""
         },
         "aggs":{
            "visits_greater_than_one":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"sessionId",
                  "min_doc_count":2
               }
            }
         },
         "aggs":{
            "visitor_count":{
               "cardinality":{
                  "field":"sessionId"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks,
Ankireddy Polu

Comment: What script? I think you are not stating your problem clearly.

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html                                                                 for calculating the bounce rate i.e (number single page visits)/(total number of visits) using the results from aggression that is visits_greater_than_one and visitor count, i would like perform the calculation and get the bounce rate.

Comment: Maybe use the `script` field in a [`value_count` aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html)?

Comment: value_count aggregation can be use in case of we are aggressing the value of field, that value of field can be manipulated using the script, but in my case we need to the meta data i.e number of documents not values in documents

Answer (score 0):

i have found a little workaround for addressing this problem

```
{
   "aggs":{
      "monthly":{
         "date_histogram":{
            "field":"timestamp",
            "interval":"month"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "visits_greater_than_one":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"sessionId",
                  "min_doc_count":2
               }
            },
                "visitor_count":{
               "cardinality":{
                  "field":"sessionId"
               }
            }
         }

      }
   }
}
```

the drawback with the approach is we need to perform the calculation separately where ever we pares the result, we will have a two different buckets one will hold the number of sessions whose have more than one entry and total number of session during that interval. using that (visitor_count - visits_greater_than_one)/visitor_count will be my bounce rate
(visitor_count - visits_greater_than_one) gives me the sessions user visited only single page